# Use of LaTex in Anki

Tags: tables, anki

I write formulas in Anki as used in LaTex and want to expand it to use LaTex to make tables, lists and similar things within Anki. When I tried this out it didn't work even though I used [latex][/latex]. Is there anything I have to download, an Add-on or so, such that it works?

example:

The following should produce a list...
[image: example where it doesn't work]
[image: how it looks on the card]

...but produces this instead

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "did not work"?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a short document that doesn’t work?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. On this site, we’d really appreciate if you post the text as a code block, so we can copy and paste it to test for ourselves.

Comment: However, it looks as if your program can’t find the `latex` executable. Is its directory in your path? Does `latex --version` from the command line work? Is there an option in Anki to specify where the executable is located?

Comment: General question [How to use LaTeX in Anki on Windows with MiKTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471146/how-to-use-latex-in-anki-on-windows-with-miktex)

Comment: Thank you @Davislor .
Well, now I found the website which does explain my question. If you have similar problems, go check this out: https://docs.ankiweb.net/math.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.